# Randomly crop pdf files and output image

Tags: command-line, pdf, image-processing

I have many pdf files in a folder. All I want to do is load a pdf file and generate 100 random crops from it and convert each crop to image of size 256x256. So if I have 100 pdf files, I will have 100x100 jpg images as output as I want to get 100 crops from 100 pdf files inside a folder. Can this process be automated? The pdf files are scientific journal papers from CiteSeerX. I have provided a [sample document](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzLkjBy4XJGKMlZCTDJEVGh5aE0/view?usp=sharing).

I would also like the random crop to focus on the places that has texts rather than on the regions with just white background. Can I enforce this using some techniques?

Comment: @DavidFoerster: 1. The pdf files are multi-paged. 2. The pdf page is simply consists of scintific journals from CiteSeex. 3. I want to crop a random square region . By 100x100 i mean i want to extract 100 crops from 100 pdf files. I am not clear about the size in millimeter I need, but later I want to convert each crop to a high quality jpg image of size about 256x256.

Comment: @DavidFoerster: Could you please look at it. I have edited my question with sample pdf.

Comment: @DavidFoerster: yes David.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need Ghostscript, Poppler utilities, and ImageMagick:

```
sudo apt install ghostscript poppler-utils imagemagick
```

Let's go through this step by step (because I need to go through this mental process myself).

### Extract a random page from a PDF

```sh
pagecount=$(pdfinfo in.pdf | sed -ne 's/^Pages:\s*//p')
page=$(($RANDOM % $pagecount + 1))
gs -q -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
  -dFirstPage="$page" -dLastPage="$page" -sOutputFile="in.$page.pdf" -f in.pdf
```

### Crop a pre-defined section from the same page

```sh
gs -q -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
  -c "[/CropBox [50 50 250 250] /PAGES pdfmark" \
  -sOutputFile=out.pdf -f "in.$page.pdf"
```

### Crop a random section from the same page

Select a decimal value for `cropsize` (in [points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography)), 1 point = 1/72 inch) that is less than both width and height.

```sh
cropsize=50
bbox=$(gs -q -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -sDEVICE=bbox -f "in.$page.pdf" 2>&1 >&- | sed -ne 's/^%%HiResBoundingBox:\s*//p')

cropbbox=$(python3 - "$cropsize" "$bbox" <<EOF
import sys, random
cropsize = float(sys.argv[1])
llx, lly, urx, ury = map(float, sys.argv[2].split(None, 3))
width = urx - llx
height = ury - lly
if width < cropsize or height < cropsize:
    print('Crop size too small for bounds', llx, lly, urx, ury, file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)

cropllx = random.uniform(0, width - cropsize) + llx
croplly = random.uniform(0, height - cropsize) + lly
cropurx = cropllx + cropsize
cropury = croplly + cropsize
print(*map(lambda x: format(x, '.6f'), (cropllx, croplly, cropurx, cropury)))
EOF
)

gs -q -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
  -c "[/CropBox [$cropbbox] /PAGES pdfmark" \
  -sOutputFile=cropped.pdf -f "in.$page.pdf"
```

### Convert a cropped PDF to JPEG

Adjust `size`, `-density` (DPI for rendering the PDF), and `-quality` (JPEG compression quality) to your needs.

```sh
size=256
convert -define pdf:use-cropbox=true -colorspace sRGB -density 600 cropped.pdf \
-flatten -resize "${size}x${size}^" -crop "${size}x${size}+0+0!" -quality 75% cropped.jpg
```

### Putting it all together: Crop N random sections from an arbitrary amount of PDFs

The result is a bit unwieldy for in-line inclusion. Therefore you need to download `crop.sh` and `crop-calc.py` [from my Gist](https://gist.github.com/davidfoerster/b1c59e58a532b7ae4458d3f205810bb5) into the same directory.

Usage:

```sh
bash /path/to/crop.sh [OPTIONS...] <N> <PDF...>
```

with:

- `N` – the count of random areas to extract per document
- `PDF...` – any number of PDF files
- `-s|--size PX` – size of the resulting images in pixels (default 256)
- `-c|--cropsize PT` – size of the document regions to crop in points (default 50)
- `-d|--density DPI` – pixel density when rendering the document (default 600)<sup>1</sup>
- `-q|--quality Q` – compression quality of the resulting image, usually in percent (default 75%)
- `--destext EXT` – the file extension (and format) of the resulting images (default `jpg`)

---

<sup>1</sup> ImageMagick sets a hard limit of 500 mio. pixels which means for a square area the value of `cropsize` ÷ 72 ⋅ `density` may not exceed √500 mio.

Comment: Works Great. Thank you so much. For maximum quality-how much dpi can I set David?

Comment: @Dharma: See the foot note